# VST GUI Faders/Sliders not updating

Tags: c++, user-interface, vst, envelope

I have a university assignment that requires me to build a simple additive synth using VST SDK 2.4.

So far I have the partials being summed and an envelope.

I think the envelope works but am not sure as it is pulling its values based on the fader/slider position, and they just don't seem to want to play ball.

I am sure it is something to do with my value/range scaling as the sustain slider appears to work.

I have spent probably too long re-checking my code and just cannot what is awry.

Not sure exactly what bits of code will be useful, so I have just attached the lot.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

ADSR.h

```
#ifndef __ADSR 
#define __ADSR

#include <math.h>

class ADSR
{
public:
    ADSR();
    ~ADSR();

    int time, internalTimer, stage;
    float process(float CurrentLevel, int attack, int decay, float sustain, int release, int* pKeyState); 
};
#endif
```

ADSR.cpp

```
#include "ADSR.h"

ADSR::ADSR()
{
    time = 0;
    stage = 4;
    internalTimer = 0;
}
ADSR::~ADSR()
{

}

float ADSR::process(float CurrentLevel, int attack, int decay, float sustain, int release, int* pKeyState)
{
    if(stage = 1 && time >= (attack + decay + internalTimer + release))
    {
        time = 0;
    }
    while(time < attack)
    {
        CurrentLevel = CurrentLevel * ((1 / attack) + 1);
        time++;
        return CurrentLevel;
    }

    while(time < (attack + decay))
    {
        CurrentLevel = CurrentLevel * (sustain / decay);
        time++;
        return CurrentLevel;
    }

    while(time > (attack + decay))
    {
        CurrentLevel = CurrentLevel * 1;
        internalTimer++;
        return CurrentLevel;
    }

    while(time < (attack + decay + internalTimer + release) && *pKeyState == 2)
    {
        CurrentLevel = CurrentLevel * (sustain / release);
        time++;
        return CurrentLevel;

    }
    return CurrentLevel;
}
```

VST_Plug_in.h

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is the most basic plug in code there is!
// All this plug in will do is apply some gain to the input
// This is done in process replacing
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef __VST_Plug_in__
#define __VST_Plug_in__

#include "audioeffectx.h"

#include <math.h>
#include "ADSR.h"



const int NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 2;
const int NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS = 2;
const int NUMBER_OF_PROGRAMS = 1;
const int NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS = 5;

enum
    {
    kGain,
    kAttack,
    kDecay,
    kSustain,
    kRelease
    };

// Base frequency (A4- 440Hz) for use in generating frequency table
    const float BASE_A4  = 440.0;
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class VST_Plug_in : public AudioEffectX
{
public:
    VST_Plug_in (audioMasterCallback audioMaster);
    ~VST_Plug_in ();

    virtual void processReplacing (float** inputs, float** outputs, VstInt32 sampleFrames);

    virtual VstInt32 processEvents (VstEvents* events);
    virtual VstInt32 canDo (char* text);

    double leftSample;
    double rightSample;
    float frequency;
    float sampleRate;
    long time;
    long* pTime;
    float gain;

    // MIDI stuff
    // MIDI data : holds data about current state of MIDI (note on/off, frequency, velocity)
    int keyDown; // true : key is down, false : no key down
    int* pkeyDown;

    long currentNote; // the MIDI note number of the last note on (key down)
    float currentVelocity; // current MIDI note velocity (0 -> 1)
    float *m_pfFrequencyTable; // will store a list of frequency values (for note->frequency conversion)

    void noteOff ();
    void noteOn (long liNote, long liVelocity);
    int getAttack(float value);
    int sendAttack();
    int getDecay(float value);
    int sendDecay();
    float getSustain(float value);
    float sendSustain();
    int getRelease(float value);
    int sendRelease();

    int maxAttack, minAttack, attack, maxDecay, minDecay, decay, minRelease, maxRelease, release;
    float sustain;

    double partial1, partial2, partial3, partial4, partial5, partial6, partial7, partial8;

    ADSR env;

    virtual void setParameter (VstInt32 index, float value);
    virtual float getParameter (VstInt32 index);
    virtual void getParameterLabel (VstInt32 index, char* label);
    virtual void getParameterDisplay (VstInt32 index, char* text);
    virtual void getParameterName (VstInt32 index, char* text); 
};

#endif
```

VST_Plug_in.cpp

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VST Plug-Ins SDK
// Version 2.4      $Date: 2005/11/15 15:14:03 $
// 
// Category     : VST 2.x SDK Samples
// Filename     : VST_Plug_in.cpp
// Created by   : Steinberg Media Technologies
// Description  : a crap additive synth
//
// © 2005, Steinberg Media Technologies, All Rights Reserved
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "VST_Plug_in.h"

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AudioEffect* createEffectInstance (audioMasterCallback audioMaster)
{
    return new VST_Plug_in (audioMaster);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VST_Plug_in::VST_Plug_in (audioMasterCallback audioMaster)
: AudioEffectX (audioMaster, NUMBER_OF_PROGRAMS, NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS)  
{
    setNumInputs (NUMBER_OF_INPUTS);        // stereo in
    setNumOutputs (NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS);      // stereo out
    setUniqueID ('Add1');   // identify
    canProcessReplacing (); // supports replacing output
    leftSample  = 0.0;
    rightSample = 0.0;
    frequency = 0.0;
    gain = 1.f;
    currentVelocity = 0.0;
    currentNote = 0;
    keyDown = 2;
    pkeyDown = &keyDown;
    time = 0;
    pTime = &time;
    partial1 = partial2 = partial3 = partial4 = partial5 = partial6 = partial7 = partial8 = 0.f;
    maxAttack = 2 * 192000;
    minAttack = 1;
    attack = 44100;
    maxDecay = 192000;
    minDecay = 1;
    decay = 22050;
    maxRelease = 4 * 192000;
    minRelease = 1;
    release = 96000;
    sustain = 1.f;
    sampleRate = getSampleRate();//get sample rate from host

    ADSR env;

    isSynth (); // Informs host that this is a VSTi

    // initialise frequency table
    m_pfFrequencyTable = new float [128] ; // 128 Midi notes
    if (m_pfFrequencyTable)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<  128; i++)
        {
            m_pfFrequencyTable[i] = BASE_A4 *powf(2.f,(i-57)/12.f) ;
        }
    }   
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VST_Plug_in::~VST_Plug_in ()
{
    // nothing to do here
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// this is where the intresting stuff happens :0

void VST_Plug_in::processReplacing (float** inputs, float** outputs, VstInt32 sampleFrames)
{
    float* out1 = outputs[0];
    float* out2 = outputs[1];
    //ADSR env;

    for(int i = 0; i < sampleFrames; i++)
    {
        // NEW : only send out audio if there is a note on currently
        frequency = m_pfFrequencyTable[currentNote];

        partial1 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*(frequency/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial2 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((2*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial3 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((3*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial4 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((4*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial5 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((5*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial6 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((6*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial7 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((7*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial8 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*time++*((8*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;

        leftSample = partial1 + partial2 + partial3 + partial4 + partial5 + partial6 + partial7 + partial8;

        leftSample = leftSample * env.process(leftSample, attack, decay, sustain, release, pkeyDown); 

        leftSample = leftSample * currentVelocity;
        leftSample = leftSample * gain;

        rightSample = leftSample;

        // write samples to output buffer 
        (*out1++) = leftSample;
        (*out2++) = rightSample;
    }
}


// NEW : overriden function, tells host what the plugin can do (see notes)

VstInt32 VST_Plug_in::canDo(char *text)
{
    if (!strcmp (text, "receiveVstEvents"))     // SimpleSynth can receive VST events
        return 1;
    if (!strcmp (text, "receiveVstMidiEvent"))  // SimpleSynth can receive VST MIDI events
        return 1;
    return -1;  // explicitly can't do; 0 => don't know 
}

// NEW : this process function is called to collect incoming VST events

VstInt32 VST_Plug_in::processEvents (VstEvents* events)
{
    // parse event list
    for (long i = 0; i < events->numEvents; i++)
    {
        if ((events->events[i])->type == kVstMidiType)
        {
            VstMidiEvent* event = (VstMidiEvent*)events->events[i];
            char* midiData = event->midiData;
            long status = midiData[0] & 0xf0;       // ignoring channel

            if (status == 0x90 || status == 0x80)   // we only look at notes
            {
                long note = midiData[1];
                long velocity = midiData[2];

                if (status == 0x80)
                {
                    velocity = 0;   
                    // set velocity to zero if it is a note off message
                }
                if (!velocity && (note == currentNote))
                {
                    noteOff ();
                }
                else
                {
                    noteOn (note, velocity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1; // indicate that we wish to receive more events
}

void VST_Plug_in::noteOn(long liNote, long liVelocity)
{
    keyDown = 1;
    time = 0;
    currentNote = liNote;

    // velocity is liVelocity /127
    currentVelocity = liVelocity / 127.f;

}

void VST_Plug_in::noteOff()
{
    keyDown = 2;
    currentVelocity = 0;
}

// this function is called whenever the fader is moved

void VST_Plug_in::setParameter (VstInt32 index, float value)
{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : gain = value;break;  
        case kAttack : attack = getAttack(value); break; //need vale in samples for envelope here
        case kDecay : decay = getDecay(value); break;
        case kSustain : sustain = getSustain(value); break;
        case kRelease : release = getRelease(value); break;
    }
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// this function is called whenever the gui requires data

// eg when it is displayed

float VST_Plug_in::getParameter (VstInt32 index)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : return gain;break;
        case kAttack : return sendAttack(); break; //need 0 - 1 val here
        case kDecay : return sendDecay();break;
        case kSustain : return sendSustain();break;
        case kRelease : return sendRelease();break;
    }
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// getParameterName places the parameter name on the plug in

void VST_Plug_in::getParameterName (VstInt32 index, char* label)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : vst_strncpy (label, "Gain", kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : vst_strncpy (label, "Attack", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : vst_strncpy (label, "Decay", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain : vst_strncpy (label, "Sustain", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : vst_strncpy (label, "Release", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// getParameterDisplay displays the parameter value on the plug-in

void VST_Plug_in::getParameterDisplay (VstInt32 index, char* text)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : dB2string(gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : float2string(attack, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : float2string(decay, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain: dB2string(sustain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : float2string(release, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }

    //linear display
    //float2string(gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);

    //dB display
    //dB2string (gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void VST_Plug_in::getParameterLabel (VstInt32 index, char* label)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : vst_strncpy (label, "dB", kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain : vst_strncpy (label, "dB", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }
}

int VST_Plug_in::getAttack(float value)
{   
    attack = minAttack + ((maxAttack-minAttack) * value);
    return attack;
}
int VST_Plug_in::sendAttack()
{   
    int retAttVal;
    retAttVal = (attack - minAttack) / (maxAttack-minAttack);
    return retAttVal;
}

int VST_Plug_in::getDecay(float value)
{
    decay = minDecay + ((maxDecay-minDecay) * value);
    return decay;
}
int VST_Plug_in::sendDecay()
{
    int retDecVal;
    retDecVal = (decay - minDecay) / (maxDecay-minDecay);
    return retDecVal;
}


float VST_Plug_in::getSustain(float value)
{
    sustain = value;
    return sustain;
}
float VST_Plug_in::sendSustain()
{
    return sustain;
}

int VST_Plug_in::getRelease(float value)
{
    release = minRelease + ((maxRelease-minRelease) * value);
    return release;
}
int VST_Plug_in::sendRelease()
{
    int retRelVal;
    retRelVal = (release - minRelease) / (maxRelease-minRelease);
    return retRelVal;
}
```

Comment: What do you want us to do?

Comment: see if you can see what's up with the faders and/or envelope (and guide me on how to correct it.) The faders for Attack, Decay, and Release load with values, the fader doesn't reflect this, and when the fader is moved it returns to 0 rather than staying where placed.

Comment: Oh and I am really unsure as to wether the envelope will work or not. Doesn't have to be elegant just ramp the level. Thank you

Comment: The issue with the faders I figured out. There were some naughty ints that should have been floats. A quick change of data type and all is functioning as expected. I have another issue that has arisen with the code since but it is not related to the title so will post a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the faders I figured out.

There were some naughty ints that should have been floats.

A quick change of data type and all is functioning as expected.

I have another issue that has arisen with the code since but it is not related to the title so will post a new question.

Thanks